# Turn enumeration into a list of custom objects? 

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enumeration:

```
public enum Translation     
{   
    English=1,
    Russian, 
    French,  
    German  
}
```

I have a custom object

```
public class MyKeyValuePair
{
    string code {set;get;}
    string text {set;get;}

}
```

I want to get all my of enumeration members into a list of MyKeyValuePair.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the "code" should just be the string representation of the integer, it sounds like you want something like:

```
// Type and property names changed for sanity
var pairs = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Translation))
                .Cast<Translation>()
                .Select(t => new KeyValuePair { 
                            Code = ((int) t).ToString(),
                            Text = t.ToString()
                        });
```

Note that using the enum value names as their text representation is very limited - you can *only* use valid C# identifiers. You may well find it beneficial in the longer term to use an attribute to describe the text, at least as an override:

```
public enum Translation {
    ...
    [Description("Traditional Chinese")]
    TraditionalChinese
}
```

Attributes also allow you to add other data - for example if you didn't want the code to just be the integer representation, you could put that in the enum. You'd need to get at the attributes with reflection. I have support for `DescriptionAttribute` within [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) which makes various enum tasks simpler, but other attributes would need a bit more work.

Again, another option would be to just build a dictionary or a set directly in code, using a collection initializer. It's not sufficiently clear what you're after, to be honest. Hope some of this helps though.

Comment: Is that attribute a built-in C# thing? o.O

Comment: @Alxandr: `DescriptionAttribute` isn't built into the language, no. It's just a regular attribute. (Attributes themselves *are* built into the language though.)

Comment: Yeah, I know that (I do write a lot of C#, and made quite an ammout of attributes myself), but what I wondered was more like; will the `DisplayAttribute` alter the `ToString` of an enum? Cause I once had to do something like this, and what I did was make my own attribute and own `ToString` method xD

Comment: @Alxandr: No, it doesn't. (I've changed to use `DescriptionAttribute` now, btw - I should have done from the start.) It may alter things in the VS designer - I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah, so you still manually have to get the attribute and it's content through reflection?

Comment: @Alxandr: Yup. (Or use Unconstrained Melody to do it for you, in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple; create a static method, something like this:

```
public static mykeyvaluePair Translate(Translation translation) {
    switch(translation) {
        case Translation.English:
            return new mykeyvaluePair { code = "en", text = "English" };
        case Translation.Russian:
            return new mykeyvaluePair { code = "ru", text = "Russian" };
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```